# How to setup the url redirect correctly after user registration and login in django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views, django-registration

So, I have setup django-registration's simple backend where the user registers and is immediately logged in to the display to my other django app fileuploader. Here is the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        # return "/upload/new"
        return "/upload/" + user.get_absolute_url()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^upload/', include('mysite.fileupload.urls')),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

import os
urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'media')}),
)
```

So after the user registers at accounts/register he/she is taken directly to the url upload/users/username

Here is the mysite.fileuplaod.urls that contains the url patterns for upload/:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from mysite.fileupload.views import PictureCreateView, PictureDeleteView
from mysite.registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login

from mysite.registration import signals
from mysite.registration.views import RegistrationView as BaseRegistrationView

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        # return "/upload/new"
        return "/upload/" + user.get_absolute_url()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'$'+get_absolute_url(),PictureCreateView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-new'),
    (r'^new/$', PictureCreateView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-new'),
    (r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)$', PictureDeleteView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-delete'),
)
```

I want to setup the exact same view as upload/new for upload/users/username. r'$'+get_absolute_url() doesn't look like the right way to do it. I would really appreciate if someone could show me the right way to do this.

Also I would like to display the user name on the fileupload view page as something like "Welcome

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load upload_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Wordseer File Uploader</h1>
    </div>
    <form id="fileupload" method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="span7">
                <span class="btn btn-primary fileinput-button">
                    <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success start">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning cancel">
                    <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete">
                    <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Delete files</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            </div>
            <div class="span5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <div class="progress progress-success progres-striped active">
                    <div class="bar" style="width:0%"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fileupload-loading"></div>
        <table class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
    </form>
    <div class="fileupload-content">
        <table class="files"></table>
        <div class="fileupload-progressbar"></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        {% if pictures %}
        <h2>Already uploaded</h2>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            {% for picture in pictures %}
            <tr>
                <td class="preview">
                    <img src="{{ picture.file.url }}">
                </td>
                <td class="name">{{ picture.slug }}</td>
                <td class="delete">
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'upload-delete' picture.id %}">
                        <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <p>(Removing from this list is left as an exercise to the reader)</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
<!-- modal-gallery is the modal dialog used for the image gallery -->
<div id="modal-gallery" class="modal modal-gallery hide fade" data-filter=":odd">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
        <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body"><div class="modal-image"></div></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn modal-download" target="_blank">
            <i class="icon-download"></i>
            <span>Download</span>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-success modal-play modal-slideshow" data-slideshow="5000">
            <i class="icon-play icon-white"></i>
            <span>Slideshow</span>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-info modal-prev">
            <i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i>
            <span>Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary modal-next">
            <span>Next</span>
            <i class="icon-arrow-right icon-white"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% upload_js %}

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/load-image.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/bootstrap-image-gallery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.fileupload-fp.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/locale.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/main.js"></script>
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/csrf.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they're already registered, then **you don't need their name in the url**. Their user id is stored in their session.

Answer (score 0):

To set url use something like:

```
url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/$", PictureCreateView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-new')
```

and move it after 'new/' url.

To display user name in template use:

```
{{ request.user.username }} or {{ request.user.get_full_name }}
```

Comment: It didn't redirect to the right page when I used "url(r"^(?P<username>\w+)/$", PictureCreateView.as_view(), {}, 'upload-new')" But more importantly how do I put the "{{ request.user.username }}" in the template? Do I put it directly or under href or something?